# In React how can I update state index of array?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a Question.
For example, I have a State like this:

```
const [data,setData] = useState([{
     name:'',
     email:''
}])
```

Now Somehow I have to update the index of the object by using **onChange**

Is this the right approach?:

```
  const handleAddChange = (e)=>{
        setData((prev)=>(prev[index]={
            ...prev[index],
            [e.target.name]:e.target.value
        })
    }
```

You can say use a temp value for this kind of operation. But I want to know, can I update the state index directly without using any temp variable?

Comment: why are you using an array for state

Comment: @abolfazlshamsollahi for to-do task management. Where index will be the id and some how If I have to update the task..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.map()` to iterate the array and update the matching index:

```
const handleAddChange = e => {
  setData(prev => 
    prev.map((o, i) => i === index
      ? { ...o, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
      : o
    )
  )
}
```